# What is this corner marking for?

Tags: volleyball

[image]

*Source: [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/VolleyballCourt.svg)*

What is this corner marking for, since the serve can now be done from anywhere behind the service line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those marks are part of the definition of the service zone. Rule 12.4 *Execution of the Service*, part 3 states

> At the moment of the service hit of take-off for a jump service, the server must not touch the court (the end line included) or the floor outside the service zone.

It continues to say they can do so once the serve is made.

Without those marks, enforcement of the rule would be down fully to judgement by sight; with them there is a much more objective standard to use.

Comment: Ah, my bad - for some reason I thought that the service area extended anywhere behind the service line. It is limited by the sidelines, though, and therefore the marks do indeed make sense. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the FIVB rules anticipate this ambiguity, by clarifying it is behind the line and within the (extended) sidelines.